# how to call an abstract class method?

Tags: java, r, rjava

I am trying to create an R function that taps into my JAVA code.

I have an abstract class, let's say `StudentGroup`, that has abstract methods, and one method `getAppropriateStudentGroup()` which returns (based on config) a class which extends `StudentGroup`. This allows calling classes to behave the same regardless of which `StudentGroups` is actually appropriate.

1. How can I use rJava to call `getAppropriateStudentGroup()`?
2. How can I call the methods on the returned class?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Java won't let you call an instance method unless you first have an instance. Naturally, you can't instantiate an abstract class, so, to the best of my knowledge, you'll have to declare `getAppropriateStudentGroup()` static and call it like so: `StudentGroup.getAppropriateStudentGroup()`.

I'm assuming you actually pass some parameters to `getAppropriateStudentGroup()` or you'll always get the same.

Option B, I misunderstood you, and you actually do *have* instances of something that extends the abstract class StudentGroup, in which case you should be able to call that method on the object without problems.

I think something's a bit confused in your question or my answer, please write back ;)

Comment: You are correct, getAppropriateStudentGroup() is a static method that I call as you've described.  There are no parameters because I base the decision on config for reasons we need not go into, but the same principle holds.  If I run a test app in my Eclipse environment I can call StudentGroup.getAppropriateStudentGroup() and receive a new instance of CompSciStudents which is a class that extends StudentGroup.  I'm just struggling with how to do this in rJava

Comment: Ok, I see what you do, but I don't understand your problem then. It looks like what you are struggling with is how to do this in "java" instead of in Eclipse. Do you mean that things work in Eclipse but not in the command line with a compiled jar? (If that's the case, the first thing I'd check is that you're really using the latest compiled version of the classes)

Comment: No, I am running Java in Eclipse.  How do I do this using rJava - the CRAN tool that allows me to make Java calls through my R code?  I'm a beginner to rJava

Comment: Darn. I mistook rJava with a typo. You're writing in R, I'm really sorry, I have no experience with that :/